# How to save string in a cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used the following code to store my text in a cookie.

```
 HttpCookie Location = new HttpCookie("Location");
            Response.Cookies.Remove("Location");
            Response.Cookies.Add(Location);
               Location.Value = "Sample Text";
 DateTime deathDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            Location.Expires = deathDate;
 Response.Cookies.Add(Location);
```

Ant this following code to retrieve the cookie in Page_Load:

```
 HttpCookie Location = new HttpCookie("Location");
            Location = Request.Cookies["Location"];
            if (Location != null)
            {
                ltlLocation.Text = Location.ToString();                            
            }
```

Now the problem is: Once I redirect to some other page and return back to this page:
My literal tool (ltlLocation.Text) will display "System.Web.HttpCookie" instead of displaying String Value "Sample Text". 
So what is the problem in my code?

Comment: Location.Value.ToString()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(Request.Cookies["Location"] != null)
      {
           ltlLocation.Text = Request.Cookies["Location"].Value;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property access:

```
ltlLocation.Text = Request.Cookies["Location"].Value;
```

Or from your example:

```
ltlLocation.Text = Location.Value;
```